# npm not picking up correct repo

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following entry in my `package.json`

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:BanksySan/cmd-line-args.git"
  }
```

However, the npm registry is still showing the repo as GitHub.

[image: npm incorrectly showing GitHub as repo location]

How do I change this?

I have tried re-publishing and unpublishing and republishing and still no change.

## UPDATE

Bug raised @ https://github.com/npm/newww/issues/966

Comment: Did you 'publish' your npm package after changes?

Comment: Try chage version and publish again. Or make unpublish. And then publish again

Comment: @VasilVanchuk, I tried changing the version, I'll give unpublishing and republishing a go.

Comment: I see 0.0.3  try make 0.0.4

Comment: @VasilVanchuk Just waiting for npm to replicate the unpublish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77714/discussion-between-banksysan-and-vasil-vanchuk).

Answer (score 0):

npm info shows the correct repository so I'm guessing you just have to wait for npmjs.com's cache to refresh. If the problem persists, I recommend you open an issue here: https://github.com/npm/newww/issues

```
$ npm info cmd-line-args

{ name: 'cmd-line-args',
  description: 'Clean parsing of command line arguments',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '0.0.4' },
  versions: [ '0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.0.4' ],
  maintainers: 'banksysan <BanksySan+npm@googlemail.com>',
  time:
   { modified: '2015-05-13T12:45:22.529Z',
     created: '2015-05-12T22:12:34.157Z',
     '0.0.1': '2015-05-12T22:12:34.157Z',
     '0.0.2': '2015-05-12T22:51:45.909Z',
     '0.0.3': '2015-05-12T23:32:48.275Z',
     '0.0.4': '2015-05-13T12:45:22.529Z' },
  keywords:
   [ 'argv',
     'command line',
     'arguments',
     'parser',
     'config',
     'environment' ],
  repository:
   { type: 'git',
     url: 'git@bitbucket.org:BanksySan/cmd-line-args.git' },
  author: 'David Banks <BanksySan@googlemail.com>',
  license: 'MIT',
  readmeFilename: 'README.md',
  version: '0.0.4',
  files: [ 'index.js', 'verify.js' ],
  dependencies: { underscore: '^1.8.3' },
  devDependencies:
   { 'grunt-cli': '^0.1.13',
     'grunt-contrib-jshint': '^0.11.0',
     'grunt-contrib-nodeunit': '^0.4.1',
     'grunt-contrib-watch': '^0.6.1',
     'grunt-mocha-cli': '^1.12.0',
     'jshint-stylish': '^1.0.1',
     'load-grunt-tasks': '^3.1.0',
     proxyquire: '^1.4.0',
     should: '^6.0.1',
     sinon: '^1.14.1',
     'time-grunt': '^1.1.0' },
  scripts: { test: 'grunt' },
  main: 'index.js',
  directories: { test: 'test' },
  gitHead: 'd948c4efc6e7b9060372e813aae897179fe4ad0c',
  dist:
   { shasum: '1b93d849ee5c85544ad2807cc0100de95535ca0b',
     tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/cmd-line-args/-/cmd-line-args-0.0.4.tgz' } }
```

Comment: Looks like that might be what I need to do, it's persisted as GitHub since `0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is probably here (or in the "github-url-to-object" module):

https://github.com/npm/newww/blob/master/presenters/package.js#L82